# MySql AFTER UPDATE trigger with field names

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables listed below.  When a field is updated on "switches" I need to insert an entry to "switch_updates" that includes the name of the field updated, the old value, and the new value.

I've included the trigger I've started but am having trouble figuring out how to pull the name of the field that was updated.

```
---------------------
|  switches         |
---------------------
|  id               |
|  name (varchar)   |
|  functional (int) |
---------------------


-----------------------------
|  switch_updates           |
-----------------------------
|  id                       |
|  field_name (varchar)     |
|  field_original (varchar) |
|  field_new (varchar)      |
-----------------------------
```

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER SwitchUpdate_Trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON switches
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT into switch_updates (id, switch_id, field_name, field_original, field_new)
    VALUES 
        (
            null,
            NEW.id, -- switch_id
                  , -- field_name?
            OLD.field_value, --?
            NEW.field_value, --?
        );
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [create trigger documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html):

You can refer to columns in the subject table (the table associated with the trigger) by using the aliases OLD and NEW. OLD.col_name refers to a column of an existing row **before** it is updated or deleted. NEW.col_name refers to the column of a new row to be inserted or an existing row **after** it is updated.

From an interesting [blog](http://www.richnetapps.com/a_very_fast_introduction_on_mysql_trigge/):

In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used as there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used as there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before they were updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after they were updated.

This means that you should be able to complete your task.

Comment: I don't know if this is true: It certainly does not follow from your quoted text. That just says what `OLD` and `NEW` refer to. The only limitation there is as far as I know is that there is no `OLD` for an `INSERT` trigger, which is trivial as there is no data before you insert.

Comment: @Nanne, I have bolded the words that clarify my statement.

Comment: It is still incorrect? It will still refer to the column of the existing before it is updated even after the update has taken place? again, you CAN use `OLD` after the row has been updated.

Comment: I'm working on a similar same task as well. It would be great if you could get which column was changed rather than write IF-ELSE for all all the column-names. Or, get all column-names and iterate through them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly find the fieldname that is updated.

What you can get is the value the row (fields) had, and the value the row (fields) will have (`OLD` and `NEW`).
You could  compare the old to the new value for all fields (manually), and if it is changed, you should insert that to your table.

Possible problems:

- You can't find out if a field wasn't in the query, or was 'updated' with the same value. In both cases the `OLD` en `NEW` value will be the same
- It's kinda labourfull

But in the end you could get what you want like this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually working on the same kind of task, and as far as I've discovered the only way to get the names of the updated fields is to check each one manually like @Nanne said.

Basic example:

```
IF OLD.name <> NEW.name THEN
    INSERT INTO audit_table (`field`, `old_value`, `new_value`)
    VALUES ('name', OLD.name, NEW.name);
END IF;
```

Repeat for however many columns you want to track. If someone knows a better way I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Did you find a better way? (I'm working on a similar problem)

Comment: @LymanZerga, sadly no... To reduce the repetition I generate the trigger programmatically, but really that's just putting a dress on a pig :(